# PHP-like static html completion in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, syntax

is it possible to achive similiar results in JavaScript ? My aim is to *not* write static html within string literals.

```
<?php
    if (someCondition) {
?>
I'm here, because PHP allows it.
<?php
    }
?>
```

For example:

```
<script>
    if (someCondition) {
</script>
I'm here, because JavaScript allows it.
<script>
    }
</script>
```

I am aware of the following solution:

```
<p id = "variable">I'm here, because JavaScript allows it.</p>
<script>
    var p = document.getElementById('variable');
    if (!someCondition) {
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not in the way you've shown. The content of `script` tags are executed as a JavaScript Program, and the contents of those will throw syntax errors because `if(someCondition) {` is not a valid program.

Comment: Its not possible. However, you can use `document.write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice thought, but it's not possible in the way you want it.

Every `<script>` element is evaluated as a JavaScript independent program, which will throw a syntax error in your case.

You'll have to generate the `<p>` element inside of your JavaScript.